# Forget all cookies on laravel Login controller

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.5 and Php 7.0 . 
I want to attach a function to clear all existing cookies set by my site before attempting login.The code of LoginController unchanged is

```
use Johnson\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;


    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }
}
?>
```

How can I remove all cookies before showing login page if not logged in?I am using default laravel login page.
When logged in I am setting various cookies to remember the pages the user were at. So I want to reset every pages number saved in cookies when they login again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use listeners for the events that laravel automatically fires, because in general, it is not good at all to alter laravel files.

Instead, the authentication in laravel [fires many events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#events), such as `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Attempting`, `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login` etc...

Then you create a listener or an event subscriber, depending on your needs, and do your stuff there. It will fire every time a user tries to authenticate, or login, or logout (you choose from the events the the Authentication provides).

Answer (score 0):

Look inside the "AuthenticateUsers" trait , you should see a "showLoginForm" function if I remember correctly! I do not have my computer next door, so I can not remember the name of the function! But if you look into this function you will see that it makes the view! You can place your code there